# Emacs: automatically replace LaTeX to Unicode symbols

Tags: unicode, emacs, latex, org-mode

In Emacs I frequently use math symbols when I write my theory summaries of math textbooks. I use org-mode to structure information and I know about at least two methods of entering special symbols:

1. Using [embedded LaTeX](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-symbols.html#Special-symbols): enter its representation in the form `\land` then press <kbd>C-c C-x \</kbd> (`org-toggle-pretty-entities`) to view it literally;
2. Using <kbd>C-x 8 RET</kbd> (`insert-char`).

I want it however to behave the following way: I enter the LaTeX representation, and it is automatically converted into the physical Unicode form (abbrev?). Is there a package for that and if not, what elisp should I write to implement this behavior?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `set-input-method` <kbd>RET</kbd> `TeX` sounds like what you want.

View available symbols by executing <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-input-method` <kbd>RET</kbd> `TeX` (or its binding `C-h I`).

If you'll want to use this often, you can customize the variable `default-input-method` and set it to `TeX`.  That way, you can activate the input method with `C-\` (for `toggle-input-method`) in any buffer where you need it.

Comment: How can I make it the default for all my buffers? I tried `(set-input-method 'TeX)` in my `.emacs` file, but this only affects the `*scratch*` buffer. I have to set it explicitly on each file found later.

Comment: Set `default-input-method` to `TeX`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [latex-pretty-symbols](https://bitbucket.org/mortiferus/latex-pretty-symbols.el/src), which may be a bit less finnicky.

Comment: The repository has moved to https://github.com/epa095/latex-pretty-symbols.el . But note that this only *displays* the symbols, it does not transform them as requested.