# emacs minor mode to expand latex

Tags: emacs, latex, notation

when i take notes, i like to write in "ascii math".

e.g. definition of continuous

```
all eps > 0, exist del > 0 . |f(x)-f(y)| < eps . |x-y| < del
```

i would like this to automatically inline unicode, as i type

```
Ɐ ε > 0, ∃ δ > 0 . |f(x)-f(y)| < ε . |x-y| < δ
```

1) does this exist, in a minor mode and independent of any latex major mode?

2) how do i substitute "tokens" in emacs. e.g. the regex "\W+all\W+" => "Ɐ" (since writing " all " is easier than "\forall")?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863576/emacs-automatically-replace-latex-to-unicode-symbols

Comment: that answers my first question, thanks! for posterity, it's `C-x RET C-\ TeX RET`

Comment: Also you can use `abbrev.el` (for expanding, e.g. \all -> \forall) and `org-toggle-pretty-entities` in `org-mode` for such behavior.

Comment: how would i do the regex "\W+all\W+" => "Ɐ"?

Comment: You have to manually define abbrevs for every "token", you can define directly "all" -> "Ɐ" in file `.abbrev_defs`.